# How to attach form with th:action to an input onfocusout

Tags: html, thymeleaf

I want to send POST request every time user focuses out of an input using thymeleaf, i've seen many examples of ataching form tag with button marked with type="submit" within using th:action, but i cannot figure out is there a way i can attach input into form tag and track only focusout events.

It would be greatly appreciated if someone could clarify if i can configure what type of events form tag can track. I have read that you supposed to make button marked with type="submit", but also seen input marked the same way, that gave me hope that maybe i can somehow attach the action to focusout event.

Comment: Events happen on the client (browser), Thymeleaf works on the server and delivers to the client regular HTML. If you would like to use client's events you would need to work with client technology, for example, JavaScript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, as @SlavaIvanov said it is no realy possible, so if you face the same task you would need to use JavaScript fucntions or some other client technology, I used JS